# How to get value from dictionary without knowing key?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to get value from dictionary but i don't know key(Because dynamic generate dictionary from database) how can i get dictionary value.

```
If you some idea share me ...
```

For Example my database string value like

```
 string jsonString =  " "FB": "[{\"title\":\"sheet1\",\"rows\":[{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{\"value\":\"Cover Group \"},{\"value\":\"Sample Variable\"},{\"value\":\"Coverpoint Name\"},{\"value\":\"Crossed cover points\"},{\"value\":\"Coverpoint Comment\"},{\"value\":\"Bin Type\"},{\"value\":\"Bin Id\"},{\"value\":\"Sample Value\"},{\"value\":\"Expected Bin Count\"},{\"value\":\"Set Max Bin\"},{\"value\":\"Not Used\"}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{\"value\":\"allCg,allSi\"},{\"value\":\"exSingle\"},{\"value\":\"exSingle\"},{},{\"value\":\"Example for single bin\"},{\"value\":\"single\"},{\"value\":\"valZero\"},{\"value\":\"1'b0\"},{\"formula\":\"1\",\"value\":1},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{},{},{},{},{\"value\":\"single\"},{\"value\":\"valOne\"},{\"value\":\"1'b1\"},{\"formula\":\"1\",\"value\":1},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{\"value\":\"ex1Bus[3:0]\"},{\"value\":\"exMulti\"},{},{\"value\":\"Example for multibin\"},{\"value\":\"multi\"},{},{\"value\":\"[0:15]\"},{\"formula\":\"16\",\"value\":16},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{},{\"value\":\"exCross\"},{\"value\":\"exSingle,exMulti\"},{\"value\":\"Example for cross\"},{\"value\":\"Implicit\"},{},{},{\"formula\":\"32\",\"value\":32},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{\"value\":\"ex2Bus[15:0]\"},{\"value\":\"exWildcard\"},{},{\"value\":\"example for wildcard\"},{\"value\":\"wildcard\"},{\"value\":\"ex_wildcard\"},{\"value\":\"16'bxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1\"},{\"formula\":\"1\",\"value\":1},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{\"value\":\"ex3Bus[4:0]\"},{\"value\":\"exImplicit\"},{},{\"value\":\"example for implicit & set max bin\"},{\"value\":\"Implicit\"},{},{},{\"formula\":\"8\",\"value\":8},{\"formula\":\"8\",\"value\":8},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{\"value\":\"ex4Bus[3:0]\"},{\"value\":\"ex4Bus\"},{},{\"value\":\"setup for ignore example\"},{\"value\":\"multi\"},{},{\"value\":\"[0:15]\"},{\"formula\":\"16\",\"value\":16},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{},{\"value\":\"exIgnore\"},{\"value\":\"exSingle,ex4Bus\"},{\"value\":\"example for ignore\"},{\"value\":\"ignore\"},{},{\"value\":\"ex4Bus([12:15])\"},{\"formula\":\"24\",\"value\":24},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{\"value\":\"ex5Bus[3:0]\"},{\"value\":\"exIllegal\"},{},{\"value\":\"example for illegal\"},{\"value\":\"illegal\"},{},{\"value\":\"[12:15]\"},{\"formula\":\"16\",\"value\":16},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{\"height\":\"undefined\",\"columns\":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}],\"metadata\":{\"widths\":[\"200\",\"200\",\"200\",\"200\",\"200\",\"200\",\"200\",\"200\",\"200\",\"200\",\"200\"],\"frozenAt\":{\"row\":0,\"col\":0}}}]""
```

FB is dynamic key and after it's value title all value i need

Comment: If you know the value or part of it you could search the `Values` property or enumerate the `Dictionary` which gives you `KeyValuePairs`.

Comment: The sample data you posted isn't a flat key-value dictionary. It contains embedded dictionaries - the base dictionary contains a `title` and a `rows`, which in turn consists of `height` and `columns` and so on. Are you asking how to parse this data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This code use for get value from dictionary value without knowing key and value..  

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString );
var javSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dfi = javSer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
string dataString= dfi.Values.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the key, but have the value and trying to get hold of the key, you can do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> testData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
testData.Add("name", "Latheesan");
testData.Add("age", "26");

KeyValuePair<string, string> searchResult 
    = testData.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Value == "Latheesan");

string key = searchResult.Key; // returns "name" here
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a sequence of all the Key/Value pairs where the value matches a target:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"One", 1}, 
    {"Two", 2}, 
    {"Another One", 1}, 
    {"Three", 3}, 
    {"Yet Another One", 1}
};

int target = 1; // For example.
var matches = dict.Where(item => item.Value == target);

foreach (var kvp in matches)
    Console.WriteLine("Key = " + kvp.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample data you posted isn't a flat key-value dictionary. It contains embedded dictionaries - the base dictionary contains a title and a rows, which in turn consists of height and columns and so on, and at some point are key-value pairs who keys are, confusingly, named 'value'. Are you asking how to parse this data structure to get all the values whose key is `value`?

What you first need to do, since this appears to be a JSON-formatted entry, is parse the JSON into a .NET data structure, using libraries like JSON.NET or [System.Web.Helpers.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538324%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). These libraries will convert the JSON string into a hierarchy of dictionaries, all of them implementing IEnumerable, so you can iterate over it, more or less like this (this is *not* compilable code, just a demonstration!):

```
public void Main()
{
    var jsonObject = Json.Decode(FB); // FB is your JSON string.
    var values = new List<string>();
    FindValues(jsonObject);
}

public void FindValues(jsonObject, values)
{
    foreach (var child in jsonObject)
    {
          if (child.key == 'value')
          {
               values.Add(child.value);
          }

          // Recursively call FindValues on child objects.
          FindValues(child, values);
    }
}
```

This C#-ish pseudo-code shows you how to go over a dictionary, then optionally drill down deeper into internal dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

How can you possibly know *which* value you need if you don't have the key?

A `Dictionary` in .NET does contain a `Keys` and `Values` collection, so if you are only interested in the values, you can use that.